# set minimum number of rows in visual studio report viewer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I am showing the total of the values in a column on every page by placing a textbox in the footer and setting the expression of that column as sum(ReportItems!Sales.Value). Now I wan't to set the number of rows in a page to a fixed value of 36. That is if the number of rows in a page is less than 36 I want to show empty rows for those rows. I know it is possible to set the number of rows in a page using group expression and using the page break for that group. But I want to show empty rows if the number of rows is less than the fixed row. Please help.

Thanks in advance